# What does the (unary) * operator do in this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, operators, splat

Given the Ruby code

```
line = "first_name=mickey;last_name=mouse;country=usa" 
record = Hash[*line.split(/=|;/)]
```

I understand everything in the second line apart from the  `*` operator - what is it doing and where is the documentation for this? (as you might guess, searching for this case is proving hard...)

Answer (score 296, accepted):

The `*` is the *splat* operator.

It expands an `Array` into a list of arguments, in this case a list of arguments to the `Hash.[]` method. (To be more precise, it expands any object that responds to `to_ary`/`to_a`, or `to_a` in Ruby 1.9.)

To illustrate, the following two statements are equal:

```
method arg1, arg2, arg3
method *[arg1, arg2, arg3]
```

It can also be used in a different context, to catch all remaining method arguments in a method definition. In that case, it does not expand, but combine:

```
def method2(*args)  # args will hold Array of all arguments
end
```

[Some more detailed information here](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/ruby-pearls-vol-1-the-splat).

Comment: In general, when used as in LHS-like situation (any time you're invoking it on a value), splat splits an array up into separate values, and when used in a RHS-like situation (any time you're using it on some previously undefined variables), it groups separate values into an array.  So `a,b,*c = d,e,f,*g` sets a=d, b=e, and c=[f,g0,g1,g2,...,gn], where g=[g0,g1,g2,...,gn]

Comment: Just for completeness, the splat operator turns an array into a bare list according to the terminology used in 'The Well Grounded Rubyist' by David A. Black

Comment: @rampion: Wonderful comment, you just mixed LHS and RHS. It's the other way round.

Answer (score 56):

The splat operator unpacks an array passed to a function so that each element is sent to the function as an individual parameter.

A simple example:

```
>> def func(a, b, c)
>>   puts a, b, c
>> end
=> nil

>> func(1, 2, 3)  #we can call func with three parameters
1
2
3
=> nil

>> list = [1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]

>> func(list) #We CAN'T call func with an array, even though it has three objects
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)
    from (irb):12:in 'func'
    from (irb):12

>> func(*list) #But we CAN call func with an unpacked array.
1
2
3
=> nil
```

That's it!

Answer (score 9):

As everyone mentions, it's a "splat". Looking for Ruby syntax is impossible, and I've asked this in other questions. The answer to that part of the question is that you search on

```
asterisk in ruby syntax
```

in Google. Google is there for you, just put what you see into words.

Anyhoo, like a lot of Ruby code, that code is quite dense. The

```
line.split(/=|;/)
```

makes an array of SIX elements, `first_name, mickey, last_name, mouse, country, usa`. Then the splat is used to make that into a Hash. Now the Ruby people always send you to look at the Splat method, since everything is exposed in Ruby. I have no idea where it is, but once you have that, you'll see that it runs a `for` through the array and builds the hash.

You would look for the code in the [core](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/) documentation. If you cannot find it (I could not), you would try to write some code like this (which works, but is NOT Ruby-like code):

```
line = "first_name=mickey;last_name=mouse;country=usa"
presplat = line.split(/=|;/)
splat = Hash.new
for i in (0..presplat.length-1)
    splat[presplat[i]] = presplat[i+1] if i%2==0
end

puts splat["first_name"]
```

and then the Ruby gang will be able to tell you why your code is silly, bad, or just plain wrong.

If you've read this far, take a read through the [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) documentation for initialization.

Basically a hash that is initialized with several arguments creates them as key value pairs:

```
Hash["a", 100, "b", 200] #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
```

So in your example this would lead to the following Hash:

```
{"first_name"=>"mickey", "last_name"=>"mouse", "county"=>"usa"}
```