# pointer in python?

Tags: python, pointers

When I was trying to figure out the use of [imp.load_module](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html?highlight=imp#imp.load_module) in Python, I got the following code ([origin page](http://nullege.com/codes/search/imp.load_module/all/-1/0/python/page:2)). It's my first time seeing the use of * in Python, is that some pointer like things?

thanks in advance

```py
import imp
import dbgp
info = imp.find_module(modname, dbgp.__path__)
_client = imp.load_module(modname, *info)
sys.modules["_client"] = _client
from _client import *
del sys.modules["_client"], info, _client
```

Comment: the operator is called "splat". It's really hard to Google "*", I know :^)

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx: What a terrible an uninformative name

Comment: I think "asterisk" is the more formal name. I do like "splat", though.

Comment: Oh, this is interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `*` on front if `info` causes the list / tuple to be unwrapped into individual arguments to the function.  You can read more about unpacking [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) in the python documentation.  this can also be done with dictionaries for named arguments, see [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)

For example,

```
def do_something(a,b,c,d):
    print("{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(a,b,c,d))

a = [1,2,3,4]
do_something(*a)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
```

EDIT:

According to comments to your question by jcomeau_ictx, the operator is called `splat`

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're talking about the `_client = imp.load_module(modname, *info)` line.

No, it's not a pointer. It expands the list passed in as an argument. Here's an example:

```
In [7]: def foo(bar, baz):
   ...:     return bar + baz
   ...: 

In [8]: l = [1,2]

In [9]: foo(l)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/Daenyth/<ipython console> in <module>()

TypeError: foo() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

In [10]: foo(*l)
Out[10]: 3
```

There's similar expansion possible for dictionaries.

```
In [12]: d = {'bar': 1, 'baz': 2}

In [13]: foo(**d)
Out[13]: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, they are variables that hold the memory address of another variable.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more. I am sure that the asker would need more than this to understand pointers