# How to expand a list to function arguments in Python

Tags: python, arguments

Is there syntax that allows you to expand a list into the arguments of a function call?

Example:

```
# Trivial example function, not meant to do anything useful.
def foo(x,y,z):
   return "%d, %d, %d" %(x,y,z)

# List of values that I want to pass into foo.
values = [1,2,3]

# I want to do something like this, and get the result "1, 2, 3":
foo( values.howDoYouExpandMe() )
```

Comment: Why don't you give a tuple to the function?

Comment: @lc2817 I'm working with a library function that I cannot change and the data passed in as arguments is already in an array.

Comment: I contradict the decision to mark this as a duplicate. Linking to the ``*args`` explanation is correct but claiming this question a duplicate is asking people to play Jeopardy. Only once you know the answer to this question (which is "use *args"), can you know to search for the question claimed to be the duplicate.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

It exists, but it's hard to search for. I think most people call it the "[splat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator)" operator.

It's in the documentation as "[Unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)".

You'd use it like this for positional arguments:

```
values = [1, 2]
foo(*values)
```

There's also one for dictionaries to call with named arguments:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
def foo(a, b):
    pass
foo(**d)
```

Answer (score 90):

You should use the * operator, like `foo(*values)` Read the Python doc [unpackaging argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Also, do read this: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

```
def foo(x,y,z):
   return "%d, %d, %d" % (x,y,z)

values = [1,2,3]

# the solution.
foo(*values)
```

Answer (score 17):

Try the following:

```
foo(*values)
```

This can be found in the Python docs as [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 16):

That can be done with:

```
foo(*values)
```