# call function with a dynamic list of arguments in python

Tags: python, web.py

I need to call a function that handles a list of arguments that can have default values:

example code:

```
web.input(name=None, age=None, desc=None, alert=None, country=None, lang=None)
```

How can I call web.input like this using a list or dictionary? I'm stuck at:

```
getattr(web, 'input').__call__()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: expand list to function arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745952/python-expand-list-to-function-arguments)

Comment: Why `getattr(web, 'input').__call__()`? Just `web.input()` is fine.

Answer (score 24):

```
my_args = {'name': 'Jim', 'age': 30, 'country': 'France'}

getattr(web, 'input')(**my_args) # the __call__ is unnecessary
```

You don't need to use getattr either, you can of course just call the method directly (if you don't want to look up the attribute from a string):

```
web.input(**my_args)
```

You can do the same thing with lists:

```
my_args_list = ['Jim', 30, 'A cool person']
getattr(web, 'input')(*my_args_list)
```

is equivalent to

```
getattr(web, 'input')('Jim', 30, 'A cool person')
```

Answer (score 11):

find [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the relevant documentation

```
web.input(*list)
web.input(**kwargs)
```

Comment: @CasperDeseyne: If you got the answer you wanted it's accepted practice to mark it `accepted`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *args and **kwargs notation to pass tuples (positional) and dictionaries (named) arguments dynamically. The next code will act the same as your **web.input(...)**.

```
keyword_args = {
   "name": None,
   "age": None,
   ...
}
web.input(**keyword_args)
```