# Function returning elements of a multi-dimensonal list in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am trying to define a function that returns elements of a multi-dimensional variable according to a nested list of indices. I am working with variables depending on multiple dimensions like, e.g.: time, altitude, latitude, longitude.

Make it 3D for now (e.g., time, altitude and latitude):

```
x = np.arange(125).reshape(5,5,5)
```

If I now want the first 4 time steps, the first 3 altitude levels and the first 2 latitudes I can do several things:

```
x[[0,1,2,3],:,:][:,[0,1,2],:][:,:,[0,1]]
```

or

```
x[ [[[0]],[[1]],[[2]],[[3]]],[[0],[1],[2]],[0,1]]
```

or

```
x[np.ix_([0,1,2,3],[0,1,2],[0,1])]
```

But what I would like to have is a function giving me back the elements like

```
def get_elements( x, l )
```

where `l` is a list of indices

```
l = [[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2],[0,1]]
```

How could this function look like? The last alternative comes pretty close but `x[np.ix_(l)]` gives me an `IndexError`.

Moreover, it would be great to have the opportunity to leave dimensions untouched. E.g., using all time steps in this pseudo-code:

```
l = [[:],[0,1,2],[0,1]]
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the signature of `np.ix_`:

```
np.ix_(*args)
```

so you need to 'expand' `l`:

```
x[np.ix_(*l)]
```

Take a look at the code for `ix_`.  Notice it does things like iterate over `args`, and returns a tuple.  Also look at other functions in `np.lib.index_tricks`.

In general, if a list gives you problems when indexing, check whether you need to a tuple instead.  Also familiarize yourself with `slice`.

Comment: Great! That was actually exactly what I was looking for. I just didn't know how to search for it. But the 'expand' did the trick. Look also here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745952/python-expand-list-to-function-arguments]

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question about making a function, using your list as you're constructing it, though, you'll need to use your `np.ix_` function:

```
def get_elements(x, l):
    return x[np.ix_(*l)]
```

---

However, I think you want this:

```
>>> x[:4,:3,:2]
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 5,  6],
        [10, 11]],

       [[25, 26],
        [30, 31],
        [35, 36]],

       [[50, 51],
        [55, 56],
        [60, 61]],

       [[75, 76],
        [80, 81],
        [85, 86]]])
```

It returns the same as this:

```
x[np.ix_([0,1,2,3],[0,1,2],[0,1])]
```

There's a great answer on slicing here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24713353/541136

You can name your slice objects and pass them like this:

```
>>> first_four_slice = slice(None, 4)
>>> first_three_slice = slice(None, 3)
>>> first_two_slice = slice(None, 2)
>>> x[first_four_slice, first_three_slice, first_two_slice]
```

You can pack them all together in a single variable too:

```
>>> slice_tuple = first_four_slice, first_three_slice, first_two_slice
>>> x[slice_tuple]
```

And get your all "time steps" (i.e., get all from that dimension) like this:

```
>>> all_slice = slice(None)
>>> x[all_slice, first_three_slice, first_two_slice]
```