# What does (ctypes.c_int * len(x))(*x) do?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am working with pyOpenGL, and OpenGL requires me to transfer data by passing a pointer and the number of bytes to transfer.

I understand that python doesn't store variables in memory the same way c does. I have found the following code that makes my program work:

```
x = [1, 2, ... ]              # some list
(ctypes.c_int * len(x))(*x)
```

However I have no idea why it works (and I don't just want to trust that I haven't just gotten lucky with how everything fell into memory). What is this code actually doing?

Comment: You don't mention what you're using that works, but you can use `sizeof` to get the number of bytes to transfer. For example: `cx = (ctypes.c_int * len(x))(*x);` `num_bytes = ctypes.sizeof(cx)`.

Comment: I assume you're passing the array as a C function argument. This works because ctypes arrays, just like C arrays, are passed as a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Yes, it is being passed as a C function argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Array):

> **The recommended way to create concrete array types is by multiplying
>   any ctypes data type with a positive integer.** Alternatively, you can
>   subclass this type and define *length* and *type* class variables.
>   Array elements can be read and written using standard subscript and
>   slice accesses; for slice reads, the resulting object is not itself an
>   Array.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> >>> from ctypes import *
> >>> TenIntegers = c_int * 10
> >>> ii = TenIntegers(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
> >>> print ii
> <c_long_Array_10 object at 0x...>
> >>> for i in ii: print i,
> ...
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> >>>
> ```

So, the first part `ctypes.c_int * len(x)` creates an array type with `len(x)` elements:

```
In [17]: ctypes.c_int * 10
Out[17]: __main__.c_int_Array_10

In [18]: ctypes.c_int * 100
Out[18]: __main__.c_int_Array_100
```

After the type creation, you should call it and pass array elements:

```
(ctypes.c_int * len(x))(*x)
#                      ^^^^
```

Created array type accepts variadic number of elements, so, you should [expand list `x` using the `*x` form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745952/python-expand-list-to-function-arguments):

```
In [24]: x = [1, 2, 3]

In [25]: (ctypes.c_int * len(x))(*x)
Out[25]: <__main__.c_int_Array_3 at 0x7f0b34171ae8>

In [26]: list((ctypes.c_int * len(x))(*x))
Out[26]: [1, 2, 3]

In [27]: (ctypes.c_int * len(x))(*x)[1]
Out[27]: 2
```

You cannot pass `x`, since `__init__` expects integers:

```
In [28]: (ctypes.c_int * len(x))(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-ff45cb7481e4> in <module>()
----> 1 (ctypes.c_int * len(x))(x)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)
```