# How to give every string of a list as parameters without giving directly the list

Tags: python, list, csv

Maybe it's not clear enough, let me explain :
I want to write into a csv file, i'm using a list with 3 strings in it for example and i want to give every elements of the list to `writer.writerow()`
as `write.writerow(['test', 'test1', 'test2'])`.

I cannot give directly the list otherwise it will print " ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'] "  in only one cell of the csv file.

I was thinking about a for loop maybe, but i'm not a beast with python so any help would be appreciated.

Couldn't find any help on the internet.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but maybe what you're after is `writer.writerow(*your_list)`, where `*` unpacks the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: expand list to function arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745952/python-expand-list-to-function-arguments)

Comment: it says Python versions < 3.5 do not support `*` in tuples, lists and sets :/

Comment: are you looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows

Comment: If you are using [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.writer), it looks like you are doing it right. It should print the strings in separate columns.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this will help you.

```
import re

test = "['test1', 'test2', 'test3']"
match = re.compile(r"'\w+'")
my_list = [t.strip("'") for t in match.findall(test)]
for line in my_list:
    writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the CSV docs, it looks like anything passed to .writerow() that isn't a string (eg., your list) is stringified.

Try this?

```
mylist = ['test', 'test1', 'test2']
for line in mylist:
    writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: It doesn't help because it prints every word on a new line, thanks anyway

Comment: Oh, I thought that's what you wanted to do. Can you give an example, using the `['test', 'test1', 'test2']` list, of what you'd like the output to be? Do you want `test, test1, test2` in one line?