# Passing a function as two parameters

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a function that takes two parameters and another function that returns those two parameters. However I can't seem to figure out how to do this. In order to simplyfy my code I will make up funcions.

```
def my_function(x, y):
    return x + y

def get_x_and_y():
    x, y = [5, 10]
    return x, y

print(my_function(get_x_and_y()))
```

So this gives an error and I'm not sure how to do this.

I know this might be answered but I'm not quite sure how to word it on google, and I have looked for a while.

Comment: `print(my_function(*get_x_and_y()))`.

Comment: See also eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745952/how-to-expand-a-list-to-function-arguments-in-python. The search term you'd be looking for is "parameter expansion" (or argument expansion).

Comment: I'm slightly amused because this kind of code would have just worked [in Perl](https://ideone.com/v7ccRl).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: @melpomene of course, the (counter) question would be: what if you'd have to pass a tuple as a single argument instead, in Perl? Would Perl do try to do the right thing by inferring from the function signature?

Comment: @Evert Perl doesn't really have tuples. You'd have to pass an array (like `[$x, $y]`). And no, nothing would be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for you question is here: [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/2319299). As suggested in Everts comment:

```
print(my_function(*get_x_and_y()))
```

where the asterisk performs the parameter expansion (also called splatting in Ruby, I love this term :) )

Answer (score 0):

Functions in Python always return exactly one item. In the case of `get_x_and_y`, that item is a tuple of length two.

So your current code is calling `my_function` with just *one* parameter, a tuple. You want to *expand* that tuple into the function's arguments, using `*`:

```
my_function(*get_x_and_y())
```