# String formatting %s in python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a little problem with my app.

Here's a code:

```
parameters_tuple = (case_name, x_rw[6], x_rw[0], x_rw[1], x_rw[2], x_rw[3], x_rw[6])

return """
        <testcase classname="performance_tests" name="%s" time="%s">
            <Type>%s</Type>
            <Name>%s</Name>
            <Request_Count>%s</Request_Count>
            <Failure_Count>%s</Failure_Count>
            <Min_Response_Time>%s</Min_Response_Time>
        </testcase>""" % parameters_tuple
```

I want to have `x_rw[6]` divided by 1000.

I've tried to do this like here:

```
parameters_tuple = (case_name, x_rw[6], x_rw[0], x_rw[1], x_rw[2], x_rw[3], x_rw[6])

return """
        <testcase classname="performance_tests" name="%s" time="%s">
            <Type>%s</Type>
            <Name>%s</Name>
            <Request_Count>%s</Request_Count>
            <Failure_Count>%s</Failure_Count>
            <Min_Response_Time>%s</Min_Response_Time>
        </testcase>""" % parameters_tuple[0], parameters_tuple[1]/1000, parameteres_tuple[2:]
```

but is not working at all.
How to make it works?

Comment: "but is not working at all": please be more specific. What is the observed and what the expected output.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745952/how-to-expand-a-list-to-function-arguments-in-python

Comment: Why not `/ 1000` when defining `parameter_tuple`?

Comment: I am just receiving TypeError: not enough arguments for format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using f-strings? This works for Python >= 3.6

You can replace your code with:

```py
f'<testcase classname="performance_tests" name="{parameters_tuple[0]}" time="%s">'
```

etc. Here, you take the value of the variables and operations inside (like it is for your division), and replace that part of the string with them.

```py
f'<Type>"{parameters_tuple[1]/1000}"</Type>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that is is interpreted like this (note the `(...)`):

```
return ("""...""" % parameters_tuple[0]), parameters_tuple[1]/1000, parameters_tuple[2:]
```

Thus you get "not enough arguments for format string" because it tries to use only the first parameter when it needs 7. Instead, you can use `(...)` to create a new tuple with all the parameters to use. Use `*` to unpack the "rest":

```
return """...""" % (parameters_tuple[0], parameters_tuple[1]/1000, *parameters_tuple[2:])
```

However, it seems much simpler to just do the `/ 1000` when defining `parameters_tuple`:

```
parameters_tuple = (case_name, x_rw[6] / 1000, x_rw[0], x_rw[1], x_rw[2], x_rw[3], x_rw[6])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parameters_tuple = (case_name, x_rw[6] / 1000, x_rw[0], x_rw[1], x_rw[2], x_rw[3], x_rw[6])
```

and

f'strings helped.

Thanks guys :)