# Calling functions and passing arguments in a more efficient way

Tags: python

**My questions is basically how I can take a piece of code and optimize it to be more dynamic.**

**Firstly let me show how I am currently doing this.**

Lets say I have a list of arguments like this:

```
argument_list = [['some_function', ['first', 'second'], 1, 2], ['another_function', ['first'], 3, 1, 5]]
```

Each of these sets of arguments correspond to a specific function to be called. Here are the two functions:

```
def some_function(number, a, b):
    print(number)
    print(a+b)


def another_function(number, c, d, e):
    print(number)
    print(c+d+e)
```

In the argument list, there is another list containing names such as "first", "second" and so on. For each of these names, the function should be called again, but only with the next name.

Currently I am doing it with a tedious loop like this:

```
for i in range(len(argument_list)):
    for j in range(len(argument_list[i][1])):
        if(argument_list[i][0] == 'some_function'):
            some_function(argument_list[i][1][j], argument_list[i][2], argument_list[i][3])
        if(argument_list[i][0] == 'another_function'):
            another_function(argument_list[i][1][j], argument_list[i][2], argument_list[i][3], argument_list[i][4])
```

As the list of arguments grows and new functions are added, it becomes a problem to add new if conditions and add the arguments manually.

My question is then, is there a way to dynamically identify which function should be called, and furthermore pass all of the arguments as a single object so that they can be evaluated in the function itself.

I read about unpacking arguments in the Python documentation, but I could not get it working with this example.

My idea is basically something like this:

```
argument_list = [{'function':'some_function', 'names':['first', 'second'], 'a':1, 'b':2}, {'function':'another_function', 'names':['first'], 'c':3, 'd':1, 'e':5}]


def some_function(param):
    print(param.name)
    print(param.a + param.b)


def another_function(param):
    print(param.name)
    print(param.c + param.d + param.e) 



for arguments in argument_list:
    #How to call the correct function here while iterating name
    #some_function(arguments) or another_function(arguments)
```

Also, if there are any suggestions on a better question title it would be great :)

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745986/10473393

Comment: Why do you have the names of functions in your list instead of having the functions themselves in the list?

Comment: Consider using *args - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/

Comment: Don't edit the solution into the question. That is what answers are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...you are in the right way to understand the general purpose decorators, `*args`, `**kwargs`! I will try to give a direction to start...

First don't over complicate the problem and forget for a moment the repetitions of the functions. Then redesign your `argument_list` maybe as:

`[{'f': function1, 'args': [list of its args], 'kwargs': {dictionary of keywords parameters}}, ...]`.

A (not elegant at all) working example

```
argument_list = [{'function':'some_function', 'names':['first', 'second'], 'args': [1, 2, 3] } , {'function':'another_function', 'names':['first'], 'args': [9, 8, 7]}]


def some_function(number, a, b, e):
    print(number)
    print(a+b)


def another_function(number, c, d, e):
    print(number)
    print(c+d+e)


for f in argument_list:
    func = eval(f['function']) # execute the string as it were a python cmd
    args = f['args']

    func(0, *args)
```

Output

```
0
3
0
24
```

**Remark** if you define `argument_list` after the declaration of the last function then you can add the function name directly instead of the string counterpart and this avoid to use `eval`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [argument (un)packing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
argument_list = [
    ['some_function', ['first', 'second'], 1, 2],
    ['another_function', ['first'], 3, 1, 5]
]

def some_function(number, a, b):
    print(number)
    print(a + b)


def another_function(number, c, d, e):
    print(number)
    print(c + d + e)


for a in argument_list:
    fnName = a[0]
    a = a[1:]
    fn = globals().get(fnName)(*a)  # Look for the function string name in global scope
```

It might be easier to use function references:

```
argument_list = [
    [some_function, ['first', 'second'], 1, 2],
    [another_function, ['first'], 3, 1, 5]
]

for a in argument_list:
    fn = a[0]
    a = a[1:]
    fn(*a)
```

Out:

```
['first', 'second']
3
['first']
9
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great. Adding the final code to the answer