# What is the meaning of '*' in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> shape=(2,2)
>>> np.random.randn(*shape)
array([[-1.64633649, -0.03132273],
   [-0.92331459,  1.05325462]])
```

I can't find it in numpy's documentation. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

This is not NumPy-specific syntax; it is Python syntax. The so-called `*`-operator is Python syntax that does sequence unpacking in argument lists (see [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)).

The use in your example is to unpack the `shape` tuple into separate arguments. This is needed because `numpy.random.randn` takes an arbitrary number of integers as parameters, not a tuple of integers.

The code from the question is equivalent to doing:

```
>>> np.random.randn(2, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

[People other places sometimes call it the 'splat'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator)  (for completeness, `**` does the same thing, but with named/keyword arguments).