# accepting return values for arguments to a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i am trying to use a function that returns values, but i want these values to be returned into a different function. An example of something that i need is below.

```
def returner():
    x=1
    y=2
    z=3
    return x,y,z
def tester(arg1,arg2,arg3):
    print arg1,arg2,arg3

tester(returner())
```

What i would like it to do is print 1,2,3  however i have not been able to do it with this because it says "tester takes exactly 3 arguments, 1 given." Is there something i am missing or is this impossible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use `*` - the splat (or star) operator:

```
tester(*returner())
```

This is argument unpacking - it unpacks the tuple of returned values into the arguments for the function.

```
>>> def test():
...    return 1,2,3
... 
>>> def test2(arg1, arg2, arg3):
...    print(arg1, arg2, arg3)
... 
>>> test2(*test())
1 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you will get your pts. soon :)

Comment: This is a nice answer but the terminology is a bit off.  Most folks call it the star-operator and the operation is called argument unpacking.  It helps to know the right terminology so you can search for it when needed.  FYI, here is a link to the docs:  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: @RaymondHettinger [Splat gets used as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator). And I did say *it unpacks the tuple of returned values into the arguments*, which is 'argument unpacking' with a bit more explanation. Either way, I edited in for clarification.