# Setting HTTP_REFERER header in Django test

Tags: django, http-referer, django-testing

I'm working on a Django web application which (amongst other things) needs to handle transaction status info sent using a `POST` request.

In addition to the HTTP security supported by the payment gateway, my view checks `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` against an entry in `settings.py` to try to prevent funny business:

```
if request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '') != settings.PAYMENT_URL and not settings.DEBUG:
    return HttpResponseForbidden('Incorrect source URL for updating payment status')
```

Now I'd like to work out how to test this behaviour.

I can generate a failure easily enough; `HTTP_REFERER` is (predictably) `None` with a normal page load:

```
def test_transaction_status_succeeds(self):
    response = self.client.post(reverse('transaction_status'), { ... })
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
```

How, though, can I fake a successful submission? I've tried setting `HTTP_REFERER` in `extra`, *e.g.* `self.client.post(..., extra={'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://foo/bar'})`, but this isn't working; the view is apparently still seeing a blank header.

Does the test client even support custom headers? Is there a work-around if not? I'm using Django 1.1, and would prefer not to upgrade just yet if at all possible.

Comment: This was not your problem, but for others who are having the difficulty I had: Django was not recognizing the headers I was sending because I didn't properly transform their names as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.client.Client.get), as [described the CGI specification](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-robinson-www-interface-00#page-8). For example, `X-CSRFToken` would be `HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN`. After transforming them I could simply use them as kwargs, as in supervacuo's answer below.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Almost right. It's actually:

```
def transaction_status_suceeds(self):
    response = self.client.post(reverse('transaction_status'), {}, HTTP_REFERER='http://foo/bar')
```

I'd missed a `**` (scatter operator / keyword argument unpacking operator / [whatever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator)) when [reading the source of `test/client.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.1.x/django/test/client.py#L290); `extra` ends up being a dictionary of extra keyword arguments to the function itself.

Comment: I got a "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'HTTP_REFERER'" when trying to use this. Maybe it changed in newer versions of django?

Comment: @StevenRogers, it sounds like you might have done `c = Client(HTTP_REFERER='http://foo/bar')` instead (the only thing I can think of that will call `__init__`). I was suggesting adding that as a kwarg to `post()` & `get()`; I just tested this on Django 1.7.3 and it seems to work fine…

Answer (score 5):

You can pass HTTP headers to the constructor of `Client`:

```
from django.test import Client
from django.urls import reverse

client = Client(
    HTTP_USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0',
    HTTP_REFERER='http://www.google.com',
)
response1 = client.get(reverse('foo'))
response2 = client.get(reverse('bar'))
```

This way you don't need to pass headers every time you make a request.

Comment: It is worth a mention that the `HTTP_HEADER` will get updated after a redirect that results from `client.get` or `client.post`. This wasn't obvious to me at first.

Comment: hello Max Malysh, where exactly should I place your HTTP headers? On .htaccess file , or in the php code ?