# How to understand '*' in below python code

Tags: python, operators, tuples

When I reading code MySQLdb, in times.py, i can not understand one line code:

```
return date(*localtime(ticks)[:3])
```

Any one can tell me what's use of '*', thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's known as the *splat* operator which turns a sequence into positional arguments to be used by that given function. There is also a *double splat* operator in case you didn't know which converts a `dict` to named arguments which are then passed to the function. Also [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator) for more relevant discussion.

As an example:

```
def printIt(*args, **kwargs):
  print 'Splat Contents=%s' % str(args)
  print 'Double Splat Contents=%s' % str(kwargs)

lst = [1, 2, 3]
dct = { 'name': 'sanjay', 'age': 666 }
printIt(*lst, **dct) # usage
```

So basically to conclude, *splat* when used in function application means "take this sequence, unpack it and pass it as positional arguments". *splat* when used in function definition means "this functions takes a variable number of positional arguments". Similar reasoning can be applied to the *double splat* operator. This is the reason the most generic function definition looks something like `def funcName(*args, **kwargs)` (as already posted in my example which can handle *any* sort of arguments).

Comment: @glglgl: [Here](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/splat.html) is one reference which can be found online. I always visualize this operator as a paint-ball hitting a solid wall which gives similar appearance. This terminology is pretty common in the Ruby community and this terminology is recently picked up by a lot of languages. Surely beats the 'unpacking arguments list' phrase I would say... ;)

Comment: That's not a useful description, though. "Splat operator" tells you nothing about what it actually does. "Unpacking operator" at least gives you an idea what it's about. You don't call a `+` a "cross operator" either, do you? Also, the Jargon File is a couple of decades old by now...

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain it by example. The following code

```
params = [1, 2, 3]
func(*params)
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
func(1, 2, 3)
```

So this basically allows you to call a function with parameters coming from a list. In you particular example there's a function call (which returns a list) and a list slicing added, but you should have figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

It unpacks the first three elements of into `localtime(ticks)` and uses them as arguments for the date function.