# Asterisk in Python 3 print function. What is it for?

Tags: python, printing

Very Quick Question. I have a print function that looks like the statement below:

```
print(*Runner(x,y))
```

What is the `*` for in this case? I have no clue what it does in this context.

Comment: What happened when you ran that code. What was your output? The single asterisk in that case you provided will unpack the values.

Comment: TypeError: print() argument after * must be a sequence, not NoneType

Comment: OK. So next question. Why are you using it? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Its an assignment. I've done some research but it hasn't helped me understand what it does exactly. So, I'm reaching out the OverFlow community.

Comment: `Runner(x,y)` returns a list or tuple. The `*` unpacks that list / tuple, passing each element from the list / tuple as a separate argument to the `print` function. See [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the Python docs and the answers in [my link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515443/what-does-the-asterisk-do-in-python-other-than-multiplication-and-exponentiation) for further details.

Comment: Ok that makes some since. Thank you.