# How to make text from user input start a new line at every space?

Tags: python, string, split, spaces

Essentially I want each new word from the user input to be on the next line, so a sentence such as: "Hello World" would appear as

```
"Hello"
"World"
```

Here is my current script:

```
EnterString = input("Enter the first word of your sentence ")
e =(EnterString)
e2 =(e.split(" "))
print (e2)
```

Which would give the result:

```
['Hello', 'world']
```

How can I make Python detect the spaces and align the words accordingly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you split the input on spaces, you get your list of each "new" word.
You can then print out each one using a loop.

```
for word in e2:
   print(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [join method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
 print("\n".join(e2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your `print` syntax as well as the fact that you are using `input` and not `raw_input`, I believe this is Python 3.x.  If so, then you can just do this:

```
print(*e2, sep="\n")
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> EnterString = input("Enter the first word of your sentence ")
Enter the first word of your sentence Hello world
>>> e = EnterString
>>> e2 = e.split()
>>> print(*e2, sep="\n")
Hello
world
>>>
```

Here is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator) on what the `*` is.

Also, `str.split` defaults to split on whitespace.  So, all you need is `e.split()`.

---

However, if you are in fact on Python 2.x (namely, Python 2.7), then you will also need to put this line at the top of your script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

The above will make `print` like it is in Python 3.x, allowing you to use it as I demonstrated.