# use function and argument as arguments for a function - strange behavior?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This question should be really easy to answer, however I didn't find anything/don't know how to search.

```
def testcall(function, argument):
    function(*argument)

testcall(print, "test")
# output:
t e s t
```

why `t e s t` and not `test`?

Comment: `*argument` is breaking the string into an array of 4 chars, so you're calling `print 't', 'e', 's', 't'`; you should declare `argument` as `*argument`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your splats are asymmetric. It should be:

```
def testcall(function, *argument):
    function(*argument)
```

In general, if you want your function to behave like another function, it should accept a splat and send a splat. [This answer explains the general case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3394898/633310)

Answer (score 4):

You are using the [splat syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2322355/2555451) (`*argument`) to break up `argument` into individual characters.  Then, you are passing these characters to `print`.  It is no different than doing:

```
>>> print('t', 'e', 's', 't')
t e s t
>>>
```

---

Remove the `*` to fix the problem:

```
>>> def testcall(function, argument):
...     function(argument)
...
>>> testcall(print, "test")
test
>>>
```

Comment: ok, but how would I use this function to call a function with 2 arguments then?

Comment: thank you! great answer, however, I think @Cuadue nails it, right?

Comment: @speendo - Yes, I agree completely. :)