# How to print i for i in list in python? it gives generator object

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, printing

I am trying to print out all the elements of a list one by one, like this

```
a=[1,2,3]

print(i for i in a)
```

how do i print out

```
1 
2
3
```

Comment: Just iterate over the list and print each element: `for i in a: print(i)`

Answer (score 4):

You want to use a [for-loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) here, not a [generator expression](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in a:
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
>>> # As a one-liner
>>> for i in a: print(i)
...
1
2
3
>>>
```

---

Or, if you want to get fancy, you can use just [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) and [argument unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2322355/2555451):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> # This is the same as doing:  print(1, 2, 3, sep="\n")
>>> print(*a, sep="\n")
1
2
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways you can accomplish what you want.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

for a_val in a:
    print a_val

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    print a[i]
```