# iterating over a tuple of iterables returned from a function

Tags: python, numpy

```
ci0 = np.random.randint(10,size=(15,))

uq,ix = np.unique(ci0, return_index=True):
for i,u in zip(uq,ix):
  print i,u
```

Is there a nice pythonic way to do this in one line? Specifically, iterate over the results of np.unique (returned as a tuple).

It seems like there should be, but the only solution I could think of is this, which I think is too obfuscating to be elegant:

```
for i,u in np.transpose(np.unique(ci0, return_index=True)):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [argument unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2322355/2555451) (splatting):

```
ci0 = np.random.randint(10,size=(15,))

for i,u in zip(*np.unique(ci0, return_index=True)):
  print i,u
```

To explain better, consider the following code:

```
func(*(1, 2, 3))
```

It is equivalent to this:

```
func(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Nice idea. I have rarely used this functionality. Thanks!