# How pass unknown set of parameters to R function

Tags: r, optparse

I have a function like

```
myfunc <- function(x, y=x){
  x+y
}
```

which (obviously) defaults the value of y to x if y is not passed to the function.

Now, I'm using `optparse` to read some command line arguments to a script which calls `myfunc`.

```
# myscript.R

option_list <- list(
  make_option(c("--x"), type="numeric"),
  make_option(c("--y"), type="numeric")
)

print(myfunc(opt$x, opt$y))
```

The problem with the code above is, it forces the user to provide a value for y (otherwise an error will be thrown). Instead, I'd like to call `myfunc` using all and only the parameters provided by the user.  How can I accomplish this in the most elegant, scalable, generalize-able way?

Note - for those familiar with Python, I think I want do something similar to dictionary unpacking using whatever values are inside `opt`.

Comment: It sort of depends on what you will be doing with those parameters. For simple summing, `...` would suffice, where you collect the arguments passed to `...` and mangle them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a named list of arguments from `optparse` that you want to provide to a function, you can do so with `do.call`:

```
# Provide x and y
opts <- list(x=2, y=3)
do.call(myfunc, opts)
# [1] 5

# Provide only x
opts <- list(x=2)
do.call(myfunc, opts)
# [1] 4
```

As you note, this is basically ["dictionary unpacking"/"splatting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator) from Python.
You could then use `optparse` to grab the values for x and y, making y an optional input on the command line:

```
# optparse.R
library(optparse)
option_list <- list(make_option("--x", type="integer", default=0),
                    make_option("--y", type="integer"))
opt <- parse_args(OptionParser(option_list=option_list))
myfunc <- function(x, y=x) x+y
do.call(myfunc, opt[names(opt) %in% c("x", "y")])
# > Rscript optparse.R --x=2 --y=3
# [1] 5
# > Rscript optparse.R --x=2
# [1] 4
```

By using the R function being called to compute the default value of y instead of the command-line parser, it is simple to make more complicated defaults for y, such as `y=min(0, x)`.

```
# optparse.R
library(optparse)
option_list <- list(make_option("--x", type="integer", default=0),
                    make_option("--y", type="integer"))
opt <- parse_args(OptionParser(option_list=option_list))
myfunc <- function(x, y=min(0, x)) x+y
do.call(myfunc, opt[names(opt) %in% c("x", "y")])
# > Rscript optparse.R --x=-2
# [1] -4
# > Rscript optparse.R --x=2
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the newer [docopt](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=docopt) over [optparse](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=optparse) as I found docopt to be

- easier to use (see below)
- widely available for many langauages, see [docopt.org](http://www.docopt.org)

Here is a minimal examples *which also provides default values* which is your concern here.  First the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

library(methods)    # as Rscript does not load it
library(docopt)

## simple helper function
myfunc <- function(x, y) as.numeric(x) + as.numeric(y)   

doc <- "Usage: myscript [-x x] [-y y]
 -x x  Numeric value for x [default: 0.0]
 -y y  Numeric value for y [default: -7.89]"

opt <- docopt(doc)

print(myfunc(opt$x, opt$y))
```

Then the usage:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ ./myscript.R --help
Usage: myscript [-x x] [-y y]
 -x x  Numeric value for x [default: 0.0]
 -y y  Numeric value for y [default: -7.89] 
edd@max:/tmp$ ./myscript.R 
[1] -7.89
edd@max:/tmp$ ./myscript.R -y 40 -x 2
[1] 42
edd@max:/tmp$
```

Note that we have to use `as.numeric()` on the values as the one thing that [docopt](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=docopt)  does not do is to guarantee / enforce a type.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Dirk.  I see your default values are both constants, but what if I want the default value of y to be something like min(0, x)?

Comment: I don't think you can have interdependencies _in the argument passed to `docopt()`_ but you should be able to reconcile it _afterwards_ once you have gotten the resulting object.  Which is exactly what the other answer does too...