# python take two integer arguments from a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

This is just part of the question. It has error that missing 1 required positional argument 'mm' when running it. 
I know the problem is that it run like time_to_minutes((h,mm),)
what can i do to make it run like time_to_minutes(h,mm)?

```
def time_to_minutes(h,mm):
    time = h*60 + mm
    return time

def extract_time(time):
    h=int(time[:-3])
    mm=int(time[-2:])
    return h,mm

def time_between(a,b):
    first = time_to_minutes(extract_time(a))
    return first
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the star (`*`) operator to [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the tuple:

```
first = time_to_minutes(*extract_time(a))
```

Comment: aka the "splat" operator :)

Comment: @AdamSmith I didn't know it's called that, thanks :-)

Comment: It's a borrowed term from other languages. Python doesn't give it a name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator

Comment: To explain what happens: if you send in a tuple as an argument it will still be one parameter, just as a list would be one or a string with two letters would be one and not two parameters. If you instead unpack the tuple with `*` it will become two separate variables (works on lists as well and dicts for named arguments (then with two `**`)).