# How to get multiple plot in PyShiny?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard, py-shiny

I have been trying, unsuccessfully, to reproduce [this minimal R Shiny app](https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/) in PyShiny. I tried to literally translate the R code to python code, but it looks like I need to dynamically name the plotname() function inside the `@render.plot` decorator. All my attempts do not return any plot. I know the problem is with the exec() line near the bottom. How do I dynamically change the function name in the loop? Any help on fixing the code below:

```
from shiny import App, render, ui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#========== helper function =======================
def do_call(what, args=[], kwargs = {}): # code picked from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722804/equivalent-to-rs-do-call-in-python
    return what(*args, **kwargs)
#=================================================
max_plots = 5

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.input_slider("n", "Number of plots", value=1, min=1, max=5),
    ui.output_ui("plots")
)

def server(input, output, session):
     
    @output
    @render.ui
    def plots():
        plot_output_list = []
        for i in range(1, input.n()+1):
            plotname = f"plot{i}"
            
            plot_output_list.append(ui.output_plot(plotname))
        return do_call(ui.TagList, plot_output_list)

    for j in range(1, max_plots+1):
        #my_i = j
        #plotname = f"plot{my_i}"
        @output
        @render.plot
        def exec(f"plot{j}")(): # this line is not correct
            fig = plt.plot(range(1, j+1), range(1, j+1))
            return fig

app = App(app_ui, server)
```

Comment: I can't get py-shiny running... but I think the problem could be with `def plotname():` which creates the same function on each of your iterations. Changing that to `exec(f"def plotname_{j}(): <your code>)` should create plotname_1 etc. Does that help at all?

Comment: Thank you smartse. plotname is dynamically created, so I tried `exec(f"def {plotname}():")`, but it is not working. Your suggestion looks promising; I will play around with it.

Comment: You mean with `plotname = f"plot{my_i}"`? that's not going to work. Put `plot{my_i}` inside the `exec`

Comment: the `def` needs to be inside the `exec`. Not sure on this, but I think the whole function needs wrapping inside `exec` i.e. the closing bracket after `return fig`

Comment: If I can get something like the following to work, I will be able to carry on: ```i = 2
def exec(f"plot{i}")(x, y):
    return x+y```. Wrapping the function in `exec` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

This solution correctly captures the context for each plot (each plot is different -- look at the axes). The original code used a single closure, defined in the loop, so all 5 graphs were the same.

The `do_call` helper is unnecessary -- just call `ui.tagList()`.

Note that you could also invoke the `render.plot` directly in `render_plot_func` instead of using the decorator, i.e. `return render.plot(f)` and remove `@render.plot`. In the case of output, you cannot use the decorator syntax because there's no function definition to annotate there.

```
from shiny import App, render, ui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# =================================================
max_plots = 5

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.input_slider("n", "Number of plots", value=1, min=1, max=5),
    ui.output_ui("plots")
)


def server(input, output, session):
    def render_plot_func(j):
        @render.plot
        def f():
            fig = plt.plot(range(1, j + 1), range(1, j + 1))
            return fig
        return f
        
    @output
    @render.ui
    def plots():
        plot_output_list = []
        for i in range(1, input.n() + 1):
            plotname = f"plot{i}"

            plot_output_list.append(ui.output_plot(plotname))
            output(render_plot_func(i), id=plotname)
        return ui.TagList(plot_output_list)

app = App(app_ui, server)
```

@sbik: your answer to your own question looks effective, but I would suggest that that this version (without the `exec` call) is to be preferred, for readability if nothing else.

Comment: this is a much better solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
from shiny import App, render, ui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


## ========== helper function =======================##
def do_call(what, args=[],
            kwargs={}):  # code picked from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722804/equivalent-to-rs-do-call-in-python
    return what(*args, **kwargs)


# =================================================
max_plots = 5

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.input_slider("n", "Number of plots", value=1, min=1, max=5),
    ui.output_ui("plots")
)


def server(input, output, session):
    @output
    @render.ui
    def plots():
        plot_output_list = []
        for i in range(1, input.n() + 1):
            plotname = f"plot{i}"

            plot_output_list.append(ui.output_plot(plotname))
        return do_call(ui.TagList, plot_output_list)

    for j in range(1, max_plots + 1):
        @output(f"plot{j}")
        @render.plot
        def exec():
            fig = plt.plot(range(1, j + 1), range(1, j + 1))
            return fig

app = App(app_ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you harsha! I your code, and get the following error. `_send_error_response: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'`. Any idea what may be causing the error? Thank you

Comment: @sbik  try with `@output(id=f"plot{j}")`

Comment: The other problem ocurred because by default it expects a function, and functions have names, so you can provide an id (str) instead

Comment: That should work with the code in the asnwer of @harsha

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did finally get a solution that works. I am posting the solution in case someone else needs it.

```
from shiny import App, render, ui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#========== helper function =======================
def do_call(what, args=[], kwargs = {}): # code picked from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722804/equivalent-to-rs-do-call-in-python
    return what(*args, **kwargs)
#=================================================
max_plots = 5

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.input_slider("n", "Number of plots", value=1, min=1, max=5),
    ui.output_ui("plots")
)

def server(input, output, session):
     
    @output
    @render.ui
    def plots():
        plot_output_list = []
        for i in range(1, input.n()+1):
            plotname = f"plot{i}"
            
            plot_output_list.append(ui.output_plot(plotname))
        return do_call(ui.TagList, plot_output_list)

    for j in range(1, max_plots+1):
        exec(f"@output\n@render.plot\ndef plot{j}():\n    fig = plt.plot(range(1, {j+1}), range(1, {j+1}))\n    return fig")

app = App(app_ui, server)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).