# Generating an unknown number of lists for a python function

Tags: python, scipy

Continuing the conversation in [Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/919684/6763056)
, I'd like to learn how to generate a random number of arguments for a function in python 2.7.

In particular, while looping over various categories, I would like to pass an unkown number of *array_like*  (or *list*s?) to `scipy.stats.f_oneway`.

A simple example that works would be:

```
list_male = [34.316349, 34.32932, 34.27, 34.33905, 34.328951]
list_female = [34.61984, 34.34275, 34.6389, 34.44709, 34.51833]
f_oneway(list_male, list_female)
```

This works yielding

```
F_onewayResult(statistic=12.15815414713931, pvalue=0.0082363437299719927)
```

because I knew that my category `gender` has only two classes `male`, `female`.

But what if I am running a loop of many categories and I do not want to predetermine specific lists? E.g, if a category column `animal` in a `pd.DataFrame` has an unknown number of classes. I would like within the loop to do something like `df['animal'].unique().tolist()` and then create *array_like* (or whatever required) to feed to `f_oneway`.

Comment: Would `f_oneway(*a_list_of_lists)` work? You can try with `a_list_of_lists = [list_male, list_female]`.

Comment: Yep, works beautifully, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with `f_oneway(...)`, but assuming that it can take a variable number of arguments, and that you have a variable number of lists, you can do this:

```
list_male = [34.316349, 34.32932, 34.27, 34.33905, 34.328951]
list_female = [34.61984, 34.34275, 34.6389, 34.44709, 34.51833]
list_both = [...]
list_neither = [...]
list_of_lists = [list_male, list_female, list_both, list_neither]

f_oneway(*list_of_lists)
```

This is accomplished with the use of the [splat operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2322355/198633), which unpacks the list contents into individual arguments