# Is there an Object spread syntax in python 2.7x like in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, object, spread-syntax

How can I spread an objects/dict(?) properties and into a new object/dict?

Simple Javascript:

```
const obj = {x: '2', y: '1'}
const thing = {...obj, x: '1'}
// thing = {x: '1', y: 1}
```

Python:

```
regions = []
for doc in locations_addresses['documents']:
   regions.append(
        {
            **doc, # this will not work
            'lat': '1234',
            'lng': '1234',

        }
    )
return json.dumps({'regions': regions, 'offices': []})
```

Comment: how about [argument unpacking?](https://caisbalderas.com/blog/python-function-unpacking-args-and-kwargs/)

Comment: `obj.copy()` and `new_obj.update({'x': '1'})`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you had [Python >=3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), you can use key-word expansion in  `dict` literal:

```
>>> d = {'x': '2', 'y': '1'}
>>> {**d, 'x':1}
{'x': 1, 'y': '1'}
```

This is sometimes referred to as "splatting".

If you are on Python 2.7, well, there is no equivalent. That's the problem with using something that is over 7 years old. You'll have to do something like:

```
>>> d = {'x': '2', 'y': '1'}
>>> x = {'x':1}
>>> x.update(d)
>>> x
{'x': '2', 'y': '1'}
```

Comment: This is a really nice approach. However, I'm getting a `SyntaxError` on Python 2.7.x

Comment: File "", line 366
    **doc,
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
I updated the question

Comment: @MatthewHarwood yep, didn't realize you were on Python 2.7. You'r SOL if you want something like that which will work with dict-literals.

Comment: @MatiasCicero yes, just realized OP was on 2.7. This only works for Python >3

Comment: Literally my first project in python and it's very legacy.  maybe next time lol! thanks for the help

Comment: @MatthewHarwood yea, especially with the release of 3.6, Python 3 is vastly superior to Python 2. python 3.7 looks like it's going to be even better.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Actually, there's something similar for older versions. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @MatiasCicero yeah, that works, but you are limited by the acceptable order of arguments, i.e., positional arguments have to come before keyword-arguments.

Comment: Is `splatting` a python specific word or a generic one? In JavaScript there is `spread syntax`.

Comment: @MohammedShareefC it's informal, but I don't think it's just Python. if you google "splat operator" you get hits for Ruby and PHP

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this by creating a `dict` based on the original one, and then doing argument unpacking for the new/overridden keys:

```py
regions.append(dict(doc, **{'lat': '1234', 'lng': '1234'}))
```

**Note:** Works in both python 2 and python 3