# dict spread in python 3 (ES6 javascript like , ... notation)

Tags: python

How do you spread a dict in python?

The ES6 JS code I need to replicate is:

```js
const geo = {'lat': 123, 'lon': 456};
const time = "2021-05-30T13:18:03+00:00"

const spreadedObject = {...geo, time: time}

console.log(spreadedObject);
```

`{ lat: 123, lon: 456, time: '2021-05-30T13:18:03+00:00' }`

There must be something like spread in python, right?

Comment: Spread Operator in Python `*`

Comment: `dict(**geo)` would make a shallow copy, and you can add arbitrary other keyword arguments to it. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47875815/3001761.

Comment: If your question is about Python, don't tag JavaScript. Just because your question *mentions* JavaScript, that doesn't mean it should be in the JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... of course I found the answer right after posting the question, so I share it for all of you

```py
geo = {"lat":123,"lon":456}
time = "2021-05-30T13:18:03+00:00"
b = {**geo, "time": time}

print(b)
```

`{'lat': 123, 'lon': 456, 'time': '2021-05-30T13:18:03+00:00'}`