# Python 3 remove chars from Tuples

Tags: python-3.x, replace

My results look like this:

```
('04', 3)
('06', 1) 
('07', 1) 
('09', 2)
```

I want them to look like this:

```
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 2
```

I've tried split (Not a string, can't do that) .replace (requires string as left operand not a tuple.) I 'think' I've tried list comprehension correctly. 
I'm not clear what I should actually be doing to accomplish my desired end result. I'm trying to use n00b functions since I'm learning this therefore, I'm ignore Lambda as I have no clue what that is. I am trying to stick to list, dictionary, comprehension, slice etc at this point.

My example below won't run as written, I'm just trying to show my last attempt. When I comment out lines 15, 16, 17, it runs and creates the example shown above.

```
fname = input("Enter file:")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"
emails = open(fname)
counts=dict()
for email in emails:
    result=email.startswith('From ')
    if result is True:
        time=(email.split()[5])
        hour=(time.split(':')[0])
        counts[hour]=counts.get(hour, 0) +1
tmp=list()
for k, v in counts.items():
    tmp.append( (k, v) )
    tmp.sort()
    for char in tmp:
        if char in "(',)":
            tmp.replace(char,'')
for k in tmp:
    print (k)
```

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: how is this code related to your problem?  use fixed data `mydata = [('04', 3), ('06', 1), ('07', 1), ('09', 2)]` and show what you want to do.

Comment: Austin: The input is a long list of exported emails. (Class work)

That was an example of the output of my script, Patrick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `[('04', 3), ('06', 1), ('07', 1), ('09', 2)]` is your input, you could just do:

```
tupls = [('04', 3), ('06', 1), ('07', 1), ('09', 2)]

for x, y in tupls:
    print(x, y)

# 04 3
# 06 1
# 07 1
# 09 2
```

Comment: Thanks Austin.
I feel like a moron after seeing your answer. it worked perfectly. I have no idea why i didn't get that. 
Thank-You.
-= Bruce

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str.join` method on a space:

```
for k in tmp:
    print (' '.join(k))
```

Comment: Thank-You for your tip!

Answer (score 1):

```
mydata = [('04', 3), ('06', 1), ('07', 1), ('09', 2)]

for tup in mydata:
    print(*tup)    # this uses the default sep = " " for print
                   # *tup provides each element of tup to print
```

Output:

```
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 2
```

See

- [proper name for python * operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator) and
- [print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to read about `sep=" "`

Comment: Thank-You for the educational links! That's a very efficient way also.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
# ....
# Rest of your code
# ....
tmp=list()
for k, v in counts.items():
    tmp.append( (int(k), int(v)) ) # !!! make it integer
    tmp.sort()

for k in tmp:
    print (k)
```

Comment: Thank-You for your example!