# How to print list value in same line?

Tags: python, list

How Can i print only value of list in same line ?
My Code is:

```
t = int(input())
for case_no in range(1, t+1):
    n = int(input())
    li = list()
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            li.append(i)
    print("Case {}: {}".format(case_no, li, sep=' ', end=''))
```

My Input Output Sample Result:

```
2
6
Case 1: [1, 2, 3, 6]
23
Case 2: [1, 23]
```

My Expected Output:

```
2
6
Case 1: 1 2 3 6
23
Case 2: 1 23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `join()` to convert your list to string -

```
" ".join(map(str, li))
```

Here your list is a list of integers and `join()` joins every string element of an iterable separated by some string (in this case " "). So, you need to convert each integer to a string first. `map()` can do that. `map()` takes a function and apply it on each element of an iterable which is passes as the second arguement (here list `li`). So, `map(str, li)` will create an iterable where each element is a string representation of every element of list `li`

So, your line would be-

```
print("Case {}: {}".format(case_no, " ".join(map(str, li)), sep=' ', end=''))
```

You can use generator expression for that too -

```
print("Case {}: {}".format(case_no, " ".join(str(i) for i in li), sep=' ', end=''))
```

In this case you are using a generator expression (think of it like list comprehension if you don't know). The generator expresssion iterates over every element of `li` and returns a stringified (don't know if that's the word) version of that element.

Also, if you just want to print the list and not maintain it for other purposes then you can just simplify it a bit -

```
t = int(input())
for case_no in range(1, t+1):
    n = int(input())
    print("Case {}: {}".format(case_no, " ".join(str(i) for i in range(1, n+1) if not n % i), sep=' ', end=''))
```

Comment: You need to convert the list elements to strings before you can join them.

Comment: `" ".join(map(str, li))`

Comment: @Barmar, right. sorry didn't see that the list is of integer. thanks

Comment: can you describe your answer please. why you use map ? and how it works ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use print to do it:

```
data = [[1,2,3,4], [2,4,6]]

for idx,d in enumerate(data,1):
    print( f"Case {idx}:", *d)  # "splat" the list
```

prints:

```
Case 1: 1 2 3 4
Case 2: 2 4 6
```

Using the splat ([*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator)) (or *unpacking argument lists*) operator to provide all elements of your list as parameters to print:

```
print( *[1,2,3,4]) == print( 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you make a string out of the list, either you need another loop to parse the list. There might be other solutions as well.

You can use a comma after the print statement to avoid adding new line.

Making a string :

```py
  print("Case {}: {}".format(case_no, "".join(str(li).split(',')).strip('[]'), sep=' ', end=''))
```

With loop:

```
print("Case {}: ".format(case_no)),
for i in li:
    print(i),
print
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make elements in list as string `li.append(str(i))` 
And then have join `" ".join(li)`