# Python copy a list and adding new elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to make the creation of new list more elegant?

```
my_list = ['apple','orange']
new_list = my_list.copy()
new_list.append('grapes')
```

Comment: Please define "more elegant".

Comment: Some [alternatives](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python-9c3e15c92bf0), such as slice: `b = a[:]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [splat](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) `*` (aka "iterable unpacking") operator to spread the list into a new list literal that includes the other item(s) you want to add, and initialize the new variable with that list.

```
my_list = ['apple','orange']
new_list = [*my_list, 'grapes']
```

Comment: Related, see [proper name for python * operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator).