# Release a tuple's elements?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a function which returns two numbers:

```
def f(x):
    return x, x+1
```

And I want to create a list based on another list , like this :

```
list_1 = [5, 8]

list_2 = [(100, f(x)) for x in list_1]
```

with the intended result to be `[ (100, 5, 6), (100, 8, 9) ]`

Instead I get : `[ (100, (5, 6)), (100, (8, 9)) ]`

How can I get the right list please ? Thanks

**NOTE**: The function f(x) is actually more complex and time-consuming and it is not efficient to either run it twice, or split in 2 functions, in order to get the elements separately.

Comment: You could have always just done a loop: `for x in list_1: a,b = f(x); list_2.append((100, a, b))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `*` before `f(x)` (this will *unpack* the tuple):

```py
def f(x):
    return x, x + 1


list_1 = [5, 8]
list_2 = [(100, *f(x)) for x in list_1]

print(list_2)
```

Prints:

```py
[(100, 5, 6), (100, 8, 9)]
```

Comment: Note for OP: this is called the "splat operator".

Comment: @Code-Apprentice isn't it called unpacking operator? Splat is in Ruby.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' "unpacking operator" might be used as well, but I haven't personally heard it called that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator for a list of opinions on the matter. Googling for "python splat operator" gives some helpful results. Since google ignores punctuation, having a name for an operator helps with searches.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' I wouldn't be surprised that Python borrows the term "splat" from Ruby (or vice versa).