# How to convert a tuple in a list to a normal list?

Tags: python, mysql, database, list, tuples

language: Python 3.7.0
mysql-connector-python==8.0.31

I'm working on a website and have just implemented a database. The response I'm getting from the database looks like this:

```
[('indigo', 'admin')]
```

How do I extract the two values from the tuple in a list and convert it to a list only?

**Expected output:**

```
["indigo", "admin"]
```

Thanks,

indigo

Comment: Instead of `fetchall()` call `fetchone()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
response=[('indigo', 'admin')]

data=[response[0][i] for i in [0,1]]

data
```

**Output**

```
['indigo', 'admin']
```

Comment: Thanks you, it works. However, the response has a red line under it with the comment: Object of type "None" is not subscriptable. I suspect this is because python does not know what the database will return and therefore may assume it can be None. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Use tuple unpacking

```python
response = [('indigo', 'admin')]
data = [*response[0]]
print(data)
```

Output: `['indigo', 'admin']`

Comment: as of 2023 this should be real answer.
Called a splat operator, positional expansion, or iterable unpacking - ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator

Answer (score 1):

For this very specific example you can just access the first element of the list `a = [('indigo', 'admin')]` via your_tuple = a[0] which returns `your_tuple = ('indigo', 'admin')`. Then this tuple can be converted to a list via `list(your_tuple)`.

In general it is better not to do these steps in between. I just put them to be more pedagogical. You get the desired result with:

```
list(a[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access the first elem of the origin list `[('indigo', 'admin')]` (it has only one elem) to get the tuple. then use `list` function to convert the tuple into list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).