# Passing list and dictionary type parameter with Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing

When I run this code

```
def func(x, y, *w, **z):
  print x
  print y
  if w:
      print w

  if z:
      print z
  else:
      print "None"

func(10,20, 1,2,3,{'k':'a'})
```

I get the result as follows.

```
10
20
(1, 2, 3, {'k': 'a'})
None
```

But, I expected as follows, I mean the list parameters (1,2,3) matching *w, and dictionary matching **z.

```
10
20
(1,2,3)
{'k':'a'}
```

Q : What went wrong? How can I pass the list and dictionary as parameters?

### Added

```
func(10,20, 10,20,30, k='a')
```

seems to be working

Comment: Those, like me, unfamiliar with the `*` and `**` syntax, can refer to e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141504/name-this-python-ruby-language-construct-using-array-values-to-satisfy-function/1141556#1141556]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put two asterisks before the dictionary:

```
func(10,20, 1,2,3,**{'k':'a'})
```

Comment: This gives what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the "input" format is, but this will work:

```
func(10,20, 1,2,3, k='a')
```

With this, you don't even need to put the k=a out there at the end, it can be anywhere after the first two arguments.  Then the 1,2,3 and other "unnamed" arguments get stuffed into a tuple (I think?) for the single-star arg.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be extra explicit, you can do

```
func(10,20,*[1,2,3],**{'k':'a'})
```

to specify (to the reader) which argument you want to go with each special-form parameter.