# Expanding tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

In the following code:

```
a = 'a'
tup = ('tu', 'p')
b = 'b'
print 'a: %s, t[0]: %s, t[1]: %s, b:%s'%(a, tup[0], tup[1], b)
```

How can I "expand" (can't figure out a better verb) `tup` so that I don't have to explicitly list all its elements?

**NOTE** That I don't want to print `tup` per-se, but its individual elements. In other words, the following code is not what I'm looking for

```
>>> print 'a: %s, tup: %s, b: %s' % (a, tup, b)
a: a, tup: ('tu', 'p'), b: b
```

The code above printed `tup`, but I want to print it's elements independently, with some text between the elements.

The following doesn't work:

```
print 'a: %s, t[0]: %s, t[1]: %s, b:%s'%(a, tup, b)
In [114]: print '%s, %s, %s, %s'%(a, tup, b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: In Ruby it's called splatting; you'll find more information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141504/name-this-python-ruby-language-construct-using-array-values-to-satisfy-function , but I don't think it's applicable in your specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the format method instead, you can just do:

`"{0}{2}{3}{1}".format(a, b, *tup)`

You have to name every paramater after `tup` because the syntax for unpacking tuples to function calls using `*` requires this.

Comment: +1 for the Python 3.0 future-proofing and readability. @bgbg: Look at [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). These are my favorite references for using the `.format()`

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to [flatten a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python), but I think in your case, constructing a new tuple by concatenation is easier.

```
'a: %s, t[0]: %s, t[1]: %s, b:%s'%((a,) + tup + (b,))
#                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> print 'a: {0}, t[0]: {1[0]}, t[1]: {1[1]}, b:{2}'.format(a, tup, b)
a: a, t[0]: tu, t[1]: p, b:b
```

You can also use named parameters if you prefer

```
>>> print 'a: {a}, t[0]: {t[0]}, t[1]: {t[1]}, b:{b}'.format(a=a, t=tup, b=b)
a: a, t[0]: tu, t[1]: p, b:b
```