# Convert array of hashes to array of structs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, arrays, struct

Let's say I have two objects: User and Race.

```
class User
  attr_accessor :first_name
  attr_accessor :last_name
end

class Race
  attr_accessor :course
  attr_accessor :start_time
  attr_accessor :end_time
end
```

Now let's say I create an array of hashes like this:

```
user_races = races.map{ |race| {:user => race.user, :race => race} }
```

How do I then convert user_races into an array of structs, keeping in mind that I want to be able to access the attributes of both user and race from the struct element? (The key thing is I want to create a new object via Struct so that I can access the combined attributes of User and Race. For example, UserRace.name, UserRace.start_time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :first_name
  attr_accessor :last_name
end

class Race
  attr_accessor :course
  attr_accessor :start_time
  attr_accessor :end_time
end

UserRace = Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name, :course, :start_time, :end_time)

def get_user_race_info      
  user_races = races.map do |r| 
    UserRace.new(r.user.first_name, r.user.last_name, 
              r.course, r.start_time, r.end_time)
  end
end
```

Now let's test the result:

```
user_races = get_user_race_info
user_races[0].first_name
user_races[0].end_time
```

Comment: If I try to put this as a method in the User class, like

  def self.fastest_time_record_holders
    races = Race.by_fastest_time
    UserRace = Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name, :course, :start_time, :end_time)
    user_races = races.map do |r| 
      UserRace.new(r.user.first_name, r.user.last_name, r.course, r.start_time, r.end_time)
    end
  end

I get a dynamic constant error.  What do I need to do?

Comment: You can't redefine the struct in your method. Put the struct definition out side the method body. I have updated my answer, please take a look

Answer (score 1):

Create a definition for the UserRace object (as a [Struct](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Struct.html)), then just make an array of said objects.

```
UserRace = Struct.new(:user, :race)

user_races = races.map { |race| UserRace.new(race.user, race) }

# ...

user_races.each do |user_race|
  puts user_race.user
  puts user_race.race
end
```

Comment: The question seems a little vague. But this seems right to me.

Comment: Yea, apologies if vague.  The key thing is I want to create a new object via Struct so that I can access the combined attributes of User and Race.  For example, UserRace.name, UserRace.start_time.  Make sense?

Comment: +1 - This is an elegant solution, but i think it doesn't answer the real question i.e it doesn't actually CONVERT array of hashes to array of structs... though it will solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

if your hash has so many attributes such that listing them all:

```
user_races = races.map{ |race| {:user => race.user, :race => race, :best_lap_time => 552.33, :total_race_time => 1586.11, :ambient_temperature => 26.3, :winning_position => 2, :number_of_competitors => 8, :price_of_tea_in_china => 0.38 } } # garbage to show a user_race hash with many attributes
```

becomes cumbersome (or if you may be adding more attributes later), you can use the `*` ("splat") operator.

[the splat operator converts an array into an argument list.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918449/what-does-the-unary-operator-do-in-this-ruby-code/918475#918475)
so you can populate Struct.new's argument list with the list of keys in your hash by doing:

```
UserRace = Struct.new(*races.first.keys)
```

of course, this assumes all hashes in your array have the same keys (in the same order).

once you have your struct defined, you can use `inject` to build the final array of objects. ([inject greatly simplifies converting many objects from one data type to another](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html).)

```
user_races.inject([]) { |result, user_race| result << UserRace.new(*user_race.values) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this :::

```
user_races = races.map{ |race| {:user => race.user, :race => race} }
```

Now create a Struct as shown below :

```
UserRace = Struct.new(:user, :race)
```

And then ::

```
user_races.each do |user_race|
   new_array << UserRace.new(user_race[:user],user_race[:race])
end
```

Haven't tested the code... should be fine... what say?

EDIT: Here I am adding the objects of UserRace to a new_array.