# Passing a hash to a function ( *args ) and its meaning

Tags: ruby

When using an idiom such as:

```
def func(*args)
  # some code
end
```

What is the meaning of `*args`? Googling this specific question was pretty hard, and I couldn't find anything.

It seems all the arguments actually appear in `args[0]` so I find myself writing defensive code such as:

```
my_var = args[0].delete(:var_name) if args[0]
```

But I'm sure there's a better way I'm missing out on.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The `*` is the *splat* (or asterisk) operator. In the context of a method, it specifies a variable length argument list. In your case, all arguments passed to `func` will be putting into an array called `args`. You could also specify specific arguments before a variable-length argument like so:

```
def func2(arg1, arg2, *other_args)
  # ...
end
```

Let's say we call this method:

```
func2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

If you inspect `arg1`, `arg2` and `other_args` within `func2` now, you will get the following results:

```
def func2(arg1, arg2, *other_args)
  p arg1.inspect       # => 1
  p arg2.inspect       # => 2
  p other_args.inspect # => [3, 4, 5]
end
```

In your case, you seem to be passing a hash as an argument to your `func`, in which case, `args[0]` will contain the hash, as you are observing.

Resources:

- [Variable Length Argument List, Asterisk Operator](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls#Variable_Length_Argument_List.2C_Asterisk_Operator)
- [What is the * operator doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918449/what-is-the-operator-doing-to-this-string-in-ruby/918475#918475)

---

**Update based on OP's comments**

If you want to pass a Hash as an argument, you should not use the splat operator. Ruby lets you omit brackets, *including those that specify a Hash* (with a caveat, keep reading), in your method calls. Therefore:

```
my_func arg1, arg2, :html_arg => value, :html_arg2 => value2
```

is equivalent to

```
my_func(arg1, arg2, {:html_arg => value, :html_arg2 => value2})
```

When Ruby sees the `=>` operator in your argument list, it knows to take the argument as a Hash, even without the explicit `{...}` notation (note that this only applies if the hash argument is the last one!).

If you want to collect this hash, you don't have to do anything special (though you probably will want to specify an empty hash as the default value in your method definition):

```
def my_func(arg1, arg2, html_args = {})
  # ...
end
```

Comment: So I have to use the defensive `if args[0]` technique when accessing the params?

Comment: @shmichael How are you calling your method? If you don't want your arguments put into an array like this, don't use the splat.

Comment: I'm using the Rails convention (e.g. `my_func arg1, arg2, :html_arg => value, :html_arg2 => value2`). Ideally I would like to receive an `args` *hash*, and not an `args` *array that might contain a hash*.