# javascript arguments parameter in ruby

Tags: ruby, function, methods, arguments

I have a function with no parameters declared in its firm, but I need to obtain them if eventually any was passed to it.

For example, in javascript I can have a function as follows:

```
function plus() {
  return operator("+", arguments);
}
```

As you can see, I can obtain the function arguments via "arguments" implicit parameter.
Does ruby have something similar to javascript argument parameter?

Thanks.

PS: I did a previous research in google, stackoverflow and [this book](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) with no result, maybe there is a workaround for this and no an official way to obtain it.

Comment: In Ruby, if you don't put any parameters, the method shouldn't take any argument, if you want to send it.You would get error as `Nomethod`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701264/passing-a-hash-to-a-function-args-and-its-meaning is actually a better Q/A set to cover your concern. Both JS and ruby are object oriented, so method/function/lambda in both are objects, but in ruby the invoking process is check more strictly, to reflect the strong typing concept.

Comment: Thanks miushock for the link, it is very useful and clarifying. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using variable length arguments:

```
def plus(*args)
  # Do something with `args` array
end
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention I tried this and works perfectly, but in the excersice, I have no parameters given. I mean, its firm is empty. +1 anyway :)

Comment: @monkeydeveloper, If you don't specify any parameter, you can't call the method with any argument.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is not possible call the function with one parameter if none was declared in the function. Thank you.

Comment: It seems I have to modify the functions firm to do the excersice.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby you can always put optional arguments in a hash, such as

```
def some_function(args = {})
end
```

and you can call it like

```
some_function :arg1 => some_integer, :arg2 => "some_string"
```

Comment: This isn't what arguments does in JavaScript.

Comment: It's not but it's how similar things are done in ruby. as far as I know ruby code usually designed not to accept unanticipated arguments. In your function definition you have to anticipate it somehow.

Comment: Actually, the splat operator is how this is done in Ruby. As @falsetru shows above.

Comment: That's of course another way to anticipate it, hash is more formal impo, but again you have to anticipate variable length in your definition