# Passing nil arguments into methords in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there any way I can make ruby method that does something even if given X number of arguments and excepted more than X number of arguments?

For example:

```
def greet (name)
  name != nil ? "Hello, ${name}!" : "Hello!"
end

print greet()
```

should return "Hello!"

Comment: Smth like `def greet (name = nil)`?

Comment: Do you mean this could take any number of names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether one wants to cover any amount of arguments, they usually use `splat` parameter:

```
def greet(*params)
  case params.size
  when 0 then "Hello!"
  when 1 then "Hello, #{params.first}!"
  else "Hello, ya all there!"
end
```

or:

```
def greet(*params)
  name, = params
  name.nil? ? "Hello!" : "Hello, #{name}!"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if you want to pass n-number of arguments, you can do it with *args (which will translate it as a list of arguments)

```
def test(*args)
  args.empty? "if true something" : "if false something"
end
```

P.S. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701264/passing-a-hash-to-a-function-args-and-its-meaning)

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
def greet(name = nil)
  name ? "Hello, #{name}!" : "Hello!"
end

>> greet("Joe")
#⇒ "Hello, Joe!"
>> greet
#⇒ "Hello!"
```

Comment: This answer hardly covers “X number of arguments,” but it’s really hard to understand the exact statement of OP.

Comment: I interpolated X == 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method which should work any number of arguments :

```
def greet(*names)
  ['Hello', *names].join(', ') + '!'
end

puts greet
# Hello!
puts greet('John')
# Hello, John!
puts greet('Jane', 'John')
# Hello, Jane, John!
```

You could add some more logic to display `"Hello, Jane, John & Jack!"`.