# How you do specify multiple arguments or parameters in Thor?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, thor

my_gem hello name1 name2 name3 give me a

> my_gem hello requires at least 1 argument: my_gem hello name

Should I just parse them and separate the arguments with a delimeter?

e.g

> my_gem hello name1,name2,name3,nameN

In the file it would look like

```
class MyCLI < Thor
  desc "hello NAMES", "say hello to names"

  def hello(names)
    say "hello #{names.split(',')}"
  end
end
```

Or is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, there is another way of doing this.

```
require 'thor'
class TestApp < Thor
    desc "hello NAMES", "long desc"
    def hello(*names)
        say "hello #{names.join('; ')}"
    end
end
```

And it can be called like this:

```
$ thor test_app:hello first second third
hello first; second; third
```

Comment: That's also known as the splat operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170037/what-does-the-star-mean-in-ruby and http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/