# Generate array of all letters and digits

Tags: ruby

Using ruby, is it possible to make an array of each letter in the alphabet and 0-9 easily?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

```
[*('a'..'z'), *('0'..'9')] # doesn't work in Ruby 1.8
```

or

```
('a'..'z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a
```

or

```
(0...36).map{ |i| i.to_s 36 }
```

(the [`Integer#to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-to_s) method converts a number to a string representing it in a desired [numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system))

Comment: Is there a particular name for the `*` operator used in this context?  It's new to me.

Comment: @Michael Burr, *splat operator*. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918449/what-is-the-operator-doing-to-this-string-in-ruby) and [here](http://theplana.wordpress.com/2007/03/03/ruby-idioms-the-splat-operator/)

Comment: please indicate in answer that the * code sample will work in Ruby 1.9 but not in Ruby 1.8

Comment: @Zabba, you just indicated it in your comment ..)

Comment: Benchmarking under Ruby 2.1 [*('a'..'z'),*('0'..'9')] is a little more than twice as fast as (0...36).map{|i|i.to_s 36} (1.450000s versus 2.26000s where n = 100,000). If inclusion of upcase is desired, use the following: [*('a'..'z'),*('A'..'Z'),*('0'..'9')]

Comment: Using the Base36 number range is **genius**! Exactly what I was looking for. I created a directory structure for file distribution. All file names are base 36 numbers. Each file is then stored in its associated directory (e.g., filename[0]).

Comment: @Nakilon could you please explain how the 0...36 work what are these numbers? i know about the three points but as a beginner, I don't know about the 0 to 36

Comment: @Nakilon want to create  array containing [a,b,c,d.....] till 'n'. if limit exceed 26, then it should increse like [a,b,c......z,aa,ab and so on]

Comment: @AnshulRiyal try this: `> ("x"..).take(5)` => `["x", "y", "z", "aa", "ab"]` -- the "endless ranges" is a new feature in 2.7 or something.

Answer (score 39):

for letters or numbers you can form ranges and iterate over them. try this to get a general idea:

```
("a".."z").each { |letter| p letter }
```

to get an array out of it, just try the following:

```
("a".."z").to_a
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also do it this way:

```
'a'.upto('z').to_a + 0.upto(9).to_a
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
alphabet_array = [*'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z', *'0'..'9']
```

Or as string:

```
alphabet_string = alphabet_array.join
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myarr = [*?a..?z]       #generates an array of strings for each letter a to z
myarr = [*?a..?z] + [*?0..?9] # array of strings a-z and 0-9
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do this:

```
("0".."Z").map { |i| i }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
letters = *('a'..'z')
```

`=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]`

Comment: Even though this may answer the question, there is no explanation of your code. Please update your answer to provide an explanation of what you are doing. Thanks!