# how do i crack sha-256 via bruteforce with ruby?

Tags: ruby, sha256

As the title says, how would one go about cracking a sha256 hash via brute-force with ruby?

I have searched everywhere, but I can't find anything. I am trying to decrypt it from a string input from the user.

Comment: simple answer = you can't

Comment: SHA-256 is a one-way hashing function. There is no "decrypting". The concept does not apply.

Comment: Do some homework here http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12392/calculation-of-time-to-crack-sha-256-hash

Comment: please read the question. how do i crack it via bruteforce, meaning it would keep hashing random strings in order and comparing them.

Comment: how much time you think you can put in?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776050/how-long-to-brute-force-a-salted-sha-512-hash-salt-provided

Comment: that is java. i am asking for ruby code to do this.

Comment: bansi as much as i want

Comment: I think @bansi is thinking light-years.

Comment: these are simple hashes i am testing against. im thinking more like minutes

Comment: I just did a calculation. assuming the string length as 10 chars having alpha numeric and special chars, you may require only 664 thousand years. try this calculator http://calc.opensecurityresearch.com/

Comment: 5 letter strings are the test subject, tho thanks for the calc.

Comment: 5 letters may take about 47 mins

Comment: so, any wau to code this?

Comment: no special code, generate all 5 char strings, then generate the sha256 of that string, compare with what you have.

Comment: but how would i get ruby to automate it for me?

Comment: The question is who will finish first, your computer working on that problem or the proverbial room full of monkeys hitting keys randomly until they produce the text of Hamlet.

Comment: nice analogy. i think my server room will do.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think the monkeys will finish first with anything more than 8 chars

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking us to write your code for you, especially something trivial, is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. If you give it a shot yourself and post what you've tried, we can help you out.

Comment: @Schwern A fair number of people do agree with you that "asking us to write your code" is off-topic, does the page you linked to make that official?  I don't see where it says that.

Comment: @WayneConrad I looked around and found [a meta post about why it's not there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x). The consensus appears to be it's a corollary of "does not show any research effort" downvote reason, and the "shortest code necessary to produce the problem" from "seeking debugging help". Why isn't it spelled out clearer? Dunno, ask a moderator?

Comment: @Schwern Thanks--that's what I was looking for.  My understanding of [the top-voted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253096/238886) is that a downvote is appropriate for asking to write code, but unless it's too broad or has some other problem, a close vote is not.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, light years are not a measure of time. (:

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to write your code for you, but I will give you a start.

1. [Create an array of all letters and digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846853/generate-array-of-all-letters-and-digits#4846888).
2. Use [Array#repeated_permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation) to go through all possible 5 character strings.
3. Use the [Digest](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html) module to generate the SHA-256 digest.

Comment: Your answer is probably longer than the actual code ;-)