# Generate a hash of all letters and digits

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

**Using ruby, how do I make a hash of each letter in the alphabet (keys) and 1-26 (values) ?**

I need to create a hash with "a" to "z" in keys and 1 to 26 in values but I do not want to write myself `alphabet = {'a'=>1,'b'=>2,....'y'=>25,'z'=>26}`

I need this in my code to print `alphabet[i] if alphabet.key?(i)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate array of all letters and digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846853/generate-array-of-all-letters-and-digits)

Answer (score 9):

```
('a'..'z').each.with_index(1).to_h
#=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5, "f"=>6, "g"=>7, "h"=>8, "i"=>9, "j"=>10, 
#    "k"=>11, "l"=>12, "m"=>13, "n"=>14, "o"=>15, "p"=>16, "q"=>17, "r"=>18, "s"=>19, 
#    "t"=>20, "u"=>21, "v"=>22, "w"=>23, "x"=>24, "y"=>25, "z"=>26}
```

Steps:

- `('a'..'z')` - create a `Range` of alphabetic letters "a" through "z" inclusive
- `each` - returns an `Enumerator`
- `with_index(1)` - returns an `Enumerator` of each element of the initial Range combined with its index (starting at 1) e.g. `[["a",1],["b",2],...]`
- `to_h` - convert the `Enumerator` to a `Hash`

**Update**:

A bit more esoteric but this will also work

```
enum = Enumerator.produce('a') {|e| e == 'z' ? raise(StopIteration) : e.succ }.tap do |e| 
  e.define_singleton_method(:[]) {|elem| find_index(elem)&.+(1) } 
  e.define_singleton_method(:to_h) { with_index(1).to_h }
end
enum['w']
#=> 23
enum['W']
#=> nil 
enum.to_h 
#=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5, "f"=>6, "g"=>7, "h"=>8, "i"=>9, "j"=>10, 
#    "k"=>11, "l"=>12, "m"=>13, "n"=>14, "o"=>15, "p"=>16, "q"=>17, "r"=>18, "s"=>19, 
#    "t"=>20, "u"=>21, "v"=>22, "w"=>23, "x"=>24, "y"=>25, "z"=>26}
```

Comment: You could also produce pairs: `enum = Enumerator.produce(['a', 1]) { |e, i| [e.succ, i.succ] }` and create the hash via `enum.take(26).to_h`

Comment: @Stefan yes however the "production" is then limitless which might be more cumbersome. I originally had `enum = Enumerator.produce(['a', 1]) { |a| a.last == 26 ? raise(StopIteration) : a.map(&:succ) }` but then the `find`/`find_index` was less succinct because I had to use block form

Answer (score 7):

With two ranges, `zip` and `to_h`

```
('a'..'z').zip(1..26).to_h
```

Comment: I tend to forget about [Enumerable#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html), as I'm mostly using [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip). The former allows for some interesting uses, here one, another being `{a:1, b:2}.zip(1..2) #=> [[[:a, 1], 1], [[:b, 2], 2]]`.

Comment: You can also use an [endless range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges): `('a'..'z').zip(1..).to_h` (for older Ruby versions there's `1.step`)

Answer (score 5):

```
Hash[('a'..'z').zip(1.upto(26))]
```

Comment: The values you have provided are actually 1-26. Not 0-25.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on requirements you may be able to save memory by using an empty hash with a default proc.

```
h = Hash.new do |_h,k|
  k.is_a?(String) && k.match?(/\A[a-z]\z/) ? (k.ord - 96) : nil
end
  #=> {}
```

```
h['a']    #=>  1
h['z']    #=> 26 
h['R']    #=> nil
h['cat']  #=> nil
h[2]      #=> nil
h[{a:1}]  #=> nil
```

See [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) and [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-match-3F).

The regular expression reads, "match the beginning of the string (`\A`) followed by one lowercase letter (`[a-z]`) followed by the end of the string (`\z`). `[a-z]` denotes a *character class*.

---

If all lowercase letters must comprise the hash's keys one may write the following.

```
('a'..'z').to_h { |c| [c, c.ord - 96] }
  #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2,..., "y"=>25, "z"=>26}
```

See [Enumerable#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h).

Answer (score 0):

There have been better answers given already, but here's an entirely different option using a `times` loop to simply increment the keys and values of a starter hash using `next`:

```
h = {"a" => 1}
25.times {h[h.keys.last.next] = h.values.last.next}
h 
#=>  {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5, "f"=>6, "g"=>7, "h"=>8, "i"=>9, "j"=>10, "k"=>11, "l"=>12, "m"=>13, "n"=>14, "o"=>15, "p"=>16, "q"=>17, "r"=>18, "s"=>19, "t"=>20, "u"=>21, "v"=>22, "w"=>23, "x"=>24, "y"=>25, "z"=>26}
```