# What does a single splat/asterisk in a Ruby argument list mean?

Tags: ruby

I was poking through the Rails 3 ActiveRecord source code today and found [a method where the entire parameter list was a single asterisk](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb#L21).

```
def save(*)
```

I couldn't find a good description of what this does (though I have some ideas based on what I know about splat arguments).

What does it do, and why would you use it?

Comment: I really like [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918449/what-is-the-operator-doing-to-this-string-in-ruby/918475#918475) of the splat operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means it can have any number of arguments (including zero) and it discards all those arguments.