# The meaning of `*` when using as a param(not like *arg, just *)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I was reading Rails code, I found this

```
def save(*)
  create_or_update || raise(RecordNotSaved)
end
```

What does the `*` do? :O
I know what happens when we use it like `*args`, but in this case, it's just plain `*`.

ref https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L119

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531990/what-does-a-single-splat-asterisk-in-a-ruby-argument-list-mean

Comment: A related, more up-to-date [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77320479/1301972) for Ruby 3.2+ is available and its answers take changes in the last 10 years into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case, save doesn't take any arguments. That's what happens with a naked splat. But, as you may be aware, calling save on an `ActiveRecord` model accepts options because this method gets overridden by `ActiveRecord::Validations` here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L47

```
# The validation process on save can be skipped by passing <tt>:validate => false</tt>. The regular Base#save method is
# replaced with this when the validations module is mixed in, which it is by default.
def save(options={})
 perform_validations(options) ? super : false
end
```

Comment: i c! :D Does the `ActiveRecord::Validations` overrides `save` because its included after `ActiveRecord::Persistence` in `ActiveRecord::Base` ? :O

Answer (score 8):

It means the same thing as it does when used with a parameter name: gobble up all the remaining arguments. Except, since there is no name to bind them to, the arguments are inaccessible. In other words: it takes any number of arguments but ignores them all.

Note that there actually *is* one way to use the arguments: when you call `super` without an argument list, the arguments get forwarded as-is to the superclass method.