# What does method_name(*) mean?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In the rails [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb) I came across following method definition `def initialize(*)`

I understand what `def foo(*a)` means but can't figure out significance of omitting identifier name after `*`. How do you access any arguments passed to this method?

Comment: for variable number of argument. like python

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I understand the concept of variable number of arguments, but how do you access these variable arguments inside `def foo(*)`

Comment: Sorry :( my comment was just a guess. I never worked on Ruby. but good question

Comment: This is a duplicate of [naked asterisk as parameter in method definition: `def f(*)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249537/naked-asterisk-as-parameter-in-method-definition-def-f), [What does a single splat/asterisk in a Ruby argument list mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531990/what-does-a-single-splat-asterisk-in-a-ruby-argument-list-mean) and [The meaning of `*` when using as a param(not like `*arg`, just `*`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939344/the-meaning-of-when-using-as-a-paramnot-like-arg-just/14939675#14939675).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks, "naked asterisk" term didn't occur to me so couldn't search the web

Comment: lolz....... naked asterisk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my guess.

It works because of second line:

```
def initialize(*)
  super
  ...
end
```

So the method receives arbitrary number of arguments and passes all of them to `super`(as you know, `super` without arguments means take all arguments from original method).

And then in this case the names for arguments are not required.

Comment: It's a safe guard to protect from changing method signatures in your class / module hierarchy: "Do whatever `super` does, I don't care about the arguments."