# How do I fix the wrong number of brackets in a generated array?

Tags: ruby

When I call `next()` I have an extraneous `[]` in `@current`. How can I fix this?

```
class Result    
  attr_accessor :current

  def initialize(*previous)
    @current = previous
    p @current
  end

  def next()
    res = Result.new(@current)
  end
end

res = Result.new([2,2], [3,3], [4,4])
nextArray = res.next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first call has 3 parameters, whereas the call in next() has only one.

try:

```
def next()
  res = Result.new(*@current)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do `Result.new(*@current)` with an asterisk before the `previous`, so the array gets "splatted" back into a list of arguments, so you're calling `Result.new` with three arguments rather than one array containing three arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It's cause `*previous` is an array. So if you call `Result.new @current` it's wrapped in next array and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try expanding the array in `@current` as separate arguments to the constructor (instead of as a single array argument):

```
def next
  res = Result.new(*@current)
end
```

See also this question explaining that asterisk operator: [What does the (unary) * operator do in this Ruby code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918449/what-is-the-operator-doing-to-this-string-in-ruby)