# Ruby's Unary * Operator

Tags: ruby, splat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the * operator doing to this string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918449/what-is-the-operator-doing-to-this-string-in-ruby)

I ran across the following code when looking for an easy way to convert an array to a hash (similar to .Net's ToDictionary method on IEnumerable... I wanted to be able to arbitrarily set the key and the value).

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
h = Hash[ *a.collect { |v| [ v, v ] }.flatten ]
```

My question is, what does the asterisk before `a.collect` do?

By the way, the code comes from http://justatheory.com/computers/programming/ruby/array_to_hash_one_liner.html

Comment: Ah, hadn't found that one yet. The asterisk is tricky to search for because google and SO filter it out of searches.

Comment: Well, now you know it’s called “splat”. :-)

Comment: The Symbol Hound search engine specializes in searching for symbols: [`ruby *`](http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby%20%2A)

Comment: Thanks @sarnold, I'd never heard of Symbol Hound before. I'll have to remember it in the future.

Comment: NB: the splat [non-]operator has the lowest precedence in the example code, so it is working on the result of this:

    `a.collect { |v| [ v, v ] }.flatten`

which is an array. the point of the splat [non-]operator in the expression is that it converts that array to a list which can then be passed to Hash[]. This is necessary because, e.g. Hash[1, 2, 3, 4] works, but Hash[[1, 2, 3, 4]] does not. Note that Hash[*[1, 2, 3, 4]] is equivalent to Hash[1, 2, 3, 4].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the splat-operator if you want to google it. It does transform an array into a list (so you can use an array as arguments to a method). It also does the opposite: it can  'slurp' a list into an array.

```
require 'date'
*date_stuff = 2012,2,29 # slurp
p date_stuff #=> [2012, 2, 29]
Date.new(*date_stuff) # regurgitate
```

Comment: Thanks for the bonus info on the opposite behavior.

Comment: isn't `a, b = *[:one, :two]` called a tuple in general programming?

Comment: @fanoy - I know nothing about tuples in general programming. Your code works; it even works without the splat (which is kinda strange).

Comment: The splat is not necessary in your first example; Ruby lets you omit the brackets when defining an array. You probably wanted something like `first, *middle, last = 1,2,3,4,5; p middle #=> [2, 3, 4]`