# Explain this Ruby Array Syntax

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

The first line of `bin/jekyll` of the [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) gem uses the following syntax:

```
$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), *%w[.. lib])
```

I can't seem to figure out what the purpose of the splat is. Running that line with and without the splat in IRB results in the same ouput `"./../lib"`.

https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/bin/jekyll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in Ruby 1.9.3, both usages of the `join` method seem to be equivalent. [Under the hood](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/file.c#L3915), the elements of an array are `join`ed to the path recursively, with special protection against infinite recursion.

Therefore, this works fine:

```
File.join 'a', ['b', ['c']]
```

One might argue that the purpose of the splat operator is to eliminate the recursion. The problem is that this:

```
File.join 'a', *['b', ['c']]
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
File.join 'a', 'b', ['c']
```

In order to eliminate the recursion, you have to `flatten` the array and *then* splat it:

```
File.join 'a', *['b', ['c']].flatten
```

---

In the context of a parameter list, the splat operator "removes" the brackets of an array, so to speak. It results in this:

```
# File.join receives 3 strings as parameters
$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib')
```

As opposed to this:

```
# File.join receives 2 parameters, one string and one array of strings
$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), ['..', 'lib'])
```

[More information about the splat operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918475/512904).

Answer (score 1):

The * flattens the arguments. Equivalent without the splat:

```
File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), ["..", "lib"])
```

Equivalent with the splat:

```
File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "..", "lib")
```

I guess in this case `File.join` treats it the same way. But see that the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-join) implies they should be flattened. Now, why the author didn't simply write it without arrays OR splats is a different matter.