# How can I filter a hash from an array of symbols?

Tags: ruby, activesupport

So I have a hash that I would like to filter based on an array:

```
h = {a: 'test1', b: 'test2', c: 'test3'}
a = [:a, :poo1, :poo2]
```

My first thought was to try:

```
h.slice(a)
```

But that returns `{}`, when I hoped it would return `{:a=>"test1"}`.  I can't seem to find a simple way of filtering my hash based on an array of symbols.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using the splat operator:

```
h.slice(*a)
```

This will produce

```
> {:a=>"test1"}
```

For an explanation what the asterisk does, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918449/what-does-the-unary-operator-do-in-this-ruby-code) link.