# How can I get a hash to return a key, val pair

Tags: ruby, hash

In the following code:

If i wanted to get the value of :a ("apple") I would use "hash[:a]". If I wanted to get the key for "apple" (:a) I would use hash.key("apple").

But how can i return a hash value pair?

```
hash = {:a => "apple", :b => "banana"}
```

e.g. check if the hash contains :a, and if it does return the following

```
=> {:a => "apple"}
```

thanks.

Comment: There is [`Hash#assoc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-assoc), but I think it skips a proper hash-based lookup. I would be tempted to use: `r = if h.exists?(k) then [k, h[k]] else nil end` (or adjusted to return a Hash).

Comment: You can do this, but shouldn't, as it uses exceptions for flow-control: `{ a: hash.fetch(:a) } rescue nil`

Comment: so best to just assign a new hash then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `Hash.entries`. Entries is returned as an array of arrays of each key + value pair, and can be easily converted to a hash using the splat operator.

```
hash.entries.each do |entry| 
  p Hash[*entry] if entry.include?(:a) 
end
=> {:a=>"apple"}
```

As suggested by user2864740, Hash#assoc can also be used (if you are using ruby > 1.9):

```
Hash[*(hash.assoc(:a))]
```

Comment: what is the * before entry for?

Comment: The * is the splat operator, which is quick idiom for converting arrays to hashes, and vice-versa. For ex: a = *{:a=>"apple",:b=>"banana"} gives => [[:a,"apple"],[:b,"banana"]] and Hash[*a.flatten] gives => {:a=>"apple",:b=>"banana"}. There are many more uses for the splat operator, which might be beyond the scope for this question, but this might be a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918449/what-does-the-unary-operator-do-in-this-ruby-code/918475#918475

Comment: *Looping* the hash entries (which is `O(n)`) and then `include?` on each one (which will find `{:foo => :a}` as well)? Why use that over: `r = if h.exists?(k) then {k => h[k]} else nil end` (which doesn't loop or look in the values) or even `Hash#assoc` (which won't have the 2nd issue)?

Comment: @user2864740: I don't think there's a .exists? method for hashes. Also, Hash#assoc is only available for ruby 1.9 onwards, so won't work  with 1.8.7 (if needed). Otherwise, you are correct that Hash#assoc can be used. I'll update my answer to reflect that

Comment: @xammy Whoops, `#exists?` is indeed wrong: I meant [`Hash#has_key?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F).

Comment: One potential issue with `Hash#assoc` is that it doesn't first perform a hash-lookup; it merely uses `==` on all keys in turn until there is a match.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Rails, you could use the [Hash::slice](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) method:

```
hash.slice(:a)
```

Comment: That's not Ruby, that's [ActiveSupport](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Slice)

Answer (score 0):

If I have a hash:

```
hash = {:a => "apple", :b => "banana"}
```

And I wanted to extract a particular key/value pair from it, in the form of a sub-hash, I'd do:

```
_key = :a
Hash[_key, hash[_key]] # => {:a=>"apple"}
```

And to do it conditionally:

```
Hash[_key, hash[_key]] if hash.key?(_key)
```

But, I'm not sure why pass a single-element hash. If I know the key, I can easily grab the value. If I need to pass them both to another method, I'd do it as an array:

```
[:a, "apple"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: [Hash#select](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/select)

```
hash = {:a => "apple", :b => "banana"}
hash.select {|k| k == :a}  #=> {:a=>"apple"}
```

Comment: Works great with ruby > 1.9, but in 1.8.x it returns an array of array, which would again need to be converted to a hash. Also in 1.8.x, it won't work by just passing key as the block param, you would need to pass both k,v. so hash.select {|k, v| k == :a}