# ruby slice with array cirteria

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I create an slice for a hash in ruby looking by an array, like this:

```
info         = { :key1 => "Lorem", :key2 => "something...", :key3 => "Ipsum" }
needed_keys  = [:key1, :key3]
info         = info.slice( needed_keys )
```

I want to receive:

```
{ :key1 => "Lorem", :key3 => "Ipsum" }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ActiveSupport's [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-slice) doesn't take an array of keys as argument, you have to pass the keys you want to extract as single arguments, for example by [splatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918449/what-does-the-unary-operator-do-in-this-ruby-code) your `needed_keys` array:

```
info.slice(:key1, :key3)
# => {:key1=>"Lorem", :key3=>"Ipsum"}

info.slice(*needed_keys)
# => {:key1=>"Lorem", :key3=>"Ipsum"}
```

Comment: It might take an array, if someone is using arrays as a key. :)

Comment: Hash#slice is from ActiveSupport, please include this in your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
info.select{|k,_| needed_keys.include? k }
```

Comment: Though less direct, another pure-Ruby way: `Hash[needed_keys.zip(info.values_at(*needed_keys))]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand array:

```
info.slice(*needed_keys)
```