# Passing an Array of Symbols to Rails' `except()!` Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, constants, symbols

Simple question, and I'm a little surprised that this isn't handled better in Rails already.

I am trying to scrub out some superfluous attributes from `params` in a number of Rails API controllers with the `except!()` method, like so:

```
params.except!( :format, :api_key, :controller, :action, :updated_at, :created_at )
```

Because these attributes are the same across a number of API endpoints, I wanted to store them in a `Constant` in the API's `BaseController`, like so:

#### In BaseController.rb

```
PARAMS_TO_SCRUB = [ :format, :api_key, :controller, :action, :updated_at, :created_at ]

params.except!( PARAMS_TO_SCRUB ) # => Doesn't work.
```

But the `except!()` method only accepts a splat of keys so none of the attributes get filtered:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/except.rb, line 11
def except!(*keys)
  keys.each { |key| delete(key) }
  self
end
```

The work around I've setup now is to create a method in the `BaseController` that scrubs the `params` with the keys instead, like so:

```
def scrub_params
  params.except!( :format, :api_key, :controller, :action, :updated_at, :created_at )
end
```

**Is there no way to store a list of symbols like this?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `*` before array variable:

```
 PARAMS_TO_SCRUB = [ :format, :api_key, :controller, :action, :updated_at, :created_at ]

 params.except!( *PARAMS_TO_SCRUB )
```

So, the method will change to:

```
 def scrub_params ex_arr
   params.except! *ex_arr
 end
```

Or some global or class variable.

Comment: Nice one! Did not know about this. More information can be found at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/918475/293280